# After server starts running ,why do sockets keep on getting connected infinitely in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, sockets

I am new to nodejs,how come sockets get connected automatically till I stop the server.It should connect one socket at a time?
After I open html page in browser sockets keep on getting connected on their own!
It is expected that only one socket should be connected after server starts running.
How can I connect one socket at a time?

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

users = [];
connections =[];  

server.listen(process.env.port || 3000);
console.log('Server running');
app.get('/',function(req,res){

res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');


   });
     io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
  connections.push(socket);
 console.log('Connected: %s sockets connected',connections.length);


socket.on('disconnect',function(data){
    connections.splice(connections.indexOf(socket), 1);
console.log('Disconnected %s sockets connected',connections.length);


   });
  socket.on('send message',function(data){  

    io.sockets.emit('new message',{msg : data});

  });

   });
```

index.html

```
    <!doctype html>
   <html>
  <head>
  <title>Chat</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap         /3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
      <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js /"></script>
    <style>
     body{

   margin-top:30px;}
 </style>
 </head>

  <body>

  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="well">
  <h3> Online users </h3>
  <ul class="list-group" id="users"> </ul>

  </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-8">
  <div class="chat" id="chat">

   <form id="messageForm">

    <div class="form-group">
     <label>Enter Message</label>
    <textarea  class="form-control" id="message"></textarea>

    </br>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  value="Send message"/>


   </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  </div>

  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

     <script>
    $(function(){
    var socket = io.connect();
    var $messageForm = $('#messageForm');
    var $message = $('#message');
    var $chat = $('#chat');
    $messageForm.submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    socket.emit('send message',  $message.val());
    $message.val(''); 

    });
    socket.on('new message',function(data){
    $chat.append('<div class="well">'+data.msg+'</div>');
    });

    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit more complete solution with some notes for you.

Socket.io has long had some snafus with multiple connections. This can and will happen for things such as intermittent connectivity between client and server to past bugs.

You may want to also checkout ws on npmjs.com see > https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws

For some reference as to how templating works in NodeJS/Express see > https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/developing-template-engines.html

Hopefully this will put you in the right direction...

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
const cons = require('consolidate'); // enables using any template engine.

server.maxConnections = 5; // you can limit connections to server if you wish.

const connections = [];

// Handle your template & engine.
app.engine('html', cons.swig); // where "swig" is the template lang u want to use.
app.set('views', 'your/path/to/views'); // where your views folder lives.
app.set('view engine', 'html'); // the extension of the templates without "."

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { /* your locals here */ });
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

  connections.push(socket);
  console.log('Connected: %s sockets connected', connections.length);

  socket.on('disconnect', function (data) {
    connections.splice(connections.indexOf(socket), 1);
    console.log('Disconnected %s sockets connected', connections.length);
  });

  socket.on('send message', function (data) { // wouldn't use event names with spaces
    io.sockets.emit('new message', { // you could do something like 'message:new' & 'message:received' for the above.
      msg: data
    });
  });

});

server.listen(process.env.port || 3000, () => {
  const address = server.address();
  const host = address.address;
  const port = address.port;
  console.log(`Server listening at ${host}:${port}.`);
});

// NOTE: Below handles ctrl-c for Win //
// This will allow for graceful shutdown of connections.
if (process.platform === "win32") { // this is required for handling on windows.
  var rl = require("readline").createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });

  rl.on("SIGINT", function () {
    process.emit("SIGINT");
  });
}

process.on("SIGINT", function () {
  connections.forEach((socket) => {
    // destroy your sockets here!
  });
  process.exit();
});
```